# UDP multicast high % of packet loss

Tags: java, udp, multicast

I'm sending packets through a multicast socket.

I'm using the max *pratical* size for the packets, 65 507 bytes (65,535 − 8 byte UDP header − 20 byte IP header).

However, this results in a 40-50% packet loss, even if the server and client are in the same computer.

After testing out some values, I noticed that I can only get a 0% packet loss if the packet size is less than 10 000 bytes.

Why is that? Is is a limitation on my laptop's network card? Or is it a problem with UDP itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm using the max pratical size for the packets, 65 507 bytes

No you aren't. 65,507 is the maximum *theoretical* size. Sizes bigger than this are *impossible* in IPv4.

The maximum *practical* size is 534 or thereabouts, whatever is required to never be fragmented. As soon as fragmentation occurs you increase the probability of a datagram loss by the same factor as the number of resulting fragments, as there is nothing in UDP to recover lost fragments.

Comment: "The **practical** limit for the data length which is imposed by the underlying IPv4 protocol is 65,507 bytes" - [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure). Anyway, I get that having such large packet will increase the chance of packet loss. But 50%? Is this a normal value for packets this large?

Comment: In practice the practical limit remains what I said, or at best the path MTU. In the absence of any data as to your network, its saturation, or your transmission or receive rates it is impossible to answer your last question.

Comment: NB I corrected Wikipedia, which gives you an idea how much you can rely on it.